# Should they add a preposition 'to' after the verb 'want'?

Tags: prepositions, to-infinitive

Sentences:

> 1) Thus, each student defines how he or she **wants** his or her stay at the residence hall to be like and adapts it to his or her needs
>
> (*Thus, each student defines how he or she **wants** his or her **to** stay at the residence hall to be like and adapts it to his or her needs*)

.

> 2) She **wants** revenge
>
> (*She **wants** **to** revenge*)

.

> 3) She **wants** me dead
>
> (*She **wants** me **to** dead / **to be** dead*)

[Link#1](http://www.linguee.com/english-spanish/search?source=auto&query=Thus%2C%20each%20student%20defines%20how%20he%20or%20she%20wants%20his%20or%20her%20st) [Link#2](https://www.facebook.com/OfficialSheWantsRevenge/timeline) [Link#3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FHccClTAdzc)

Question:

> Should they add a preposition **'to'** after the verb **'want'**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb **want** can be used in several ways. According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/want), the relevant options for these contexts are

> I want some chocolate [*+ noun*]
>   I want to eat [*+ to + verb infinitive*]
>   I want you to eat [*+ object + to + verb infinitive*]
>   I want it sent [*+object + past participle*]

---

> Thus, each student defines how he or she wants his or her stay at the residence hall to be like and adapts it to his or her needs

The object is **stay**, which in this context is a noun, so no **to** is required.

> She wants revenge

The object is **revenge** which can only be a noun, so no **to** is required. The corresponding verb is **avenge**.

> She wants me dead

The object is **me**, and **dead** is a participle that the speaker wants invoked on the object. No **to** is required for a past participle.

> She wants me to be dead

The verb **be** is a verb infinitive and does require **to**. This is not a natural sentence, and most speakers would use the participle version. It would be completely natural if the participle were replaced by a normal adjective:

> She wants me to be nice

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, ***She wants me to dead** is not proper English. You should say *She wants me dead*.

Generally, when *to want* is followed by a noun or by an adjective, like *revenge* or *dead*, *to* cannot be used. *To* can only be used if another verb follows it.